# RewriteCond executes curl and matches returned string pattern

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, curl, httpd.conf

I have a token in cookie which i want to validate before redirecting. 
The validation can be done using a curl call. as shown below

In my **httpd.conf** file under **Virtualhost** tag i have this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond curl --request POST --header "X-My-Token:MGNhZTdkMzAtMzk4Yi00NTdlLWI5NmItMGVhYWZhNjM0NGNi" http://myhost.com:8888/saml-idp/api/validate-token !^.*"valid":true.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://SuccessURL.com
```

It gives me **RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters**

I know the syntax for RewriteCond can not be this way.

Please suggest me how can i execute this curl call and check the returned response before redirecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this even might be doable (with [prg: External Rewriting Program](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg)), really, just don't do it. Write a simple php (or whatever) script.

You have the `prg:` example [here](http://www.kuplen.at/2009/04/mod_rewrite-with-rewritemap-external-rewriting-program/comment-page-1/), but read the comments first :)